# How to covert .m matlab file to exe

Tags: matlab, executable, matlab-deployment

I have a .m matlab file that I want to covert it to executable 
but the problem I follow the steps written in youtube videos but still there is a problem

I think the main problem is that I have different directories used in my .m file 
which I don't know how to change them to let my exe to be used in other computers

I want some help here if you know a way to convert such .m file that is linked to the existence of additional files

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation and examples of the MATLAB Compiler? Which YouTube video(s) are you referring to?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke599czEmxU

Comment: I would refer to the official MathWorks documentation and examples rather than some random YouTube video

Comment: What is the error you get when you run exe? Also add some disp statements in your code to see whether exe is stopping after some point.

Answer (score 0):

I would type in the command window:

```
deploytool
```

it opens a gui that lets you create a standalone windows applications, at mathworks.com there are some videos that explain the procedure but it is very simple. For what concernes the directories, always use in your code relative paths and the function "fullfile" that builds the path adding the right separators (separators differ from Windows () and Unix systems(/)). Then in the deploytool it is sufficient to include the directories your code uses and these will be the same for every computer uses yuour application. I would also look for the Matlab Runtime Compiler, MRC, that is required(don't worry it is free=)) to launch the application in a machine that has not Matlab installed.
Hope this hints are useful.

Comment: I used deploytool already and did the steps to include all my files and I downloaded MRC also but when we run the exe it does nothing or it generates an error ...... and in my code we used                         addpath('C:\Users\Randa\Documents\MATLAB\mmread');

cd('C:\Users\Randa\Documents\MATLAB\matlab');

Comment: Just to understand, have you built something like a GUI? and you run it on your own computer(Randa)? maybe the problem is addpath, but i can not help you since i can not understand where is the problem.. can you post the error or the code?

Comment: maybe [this page](http://www.mathworks.it/support/solutions/en/data/1-QXFMQ/) can be helpful